# AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'set_attributes_from_name' when using ArrayField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I tried setting lazy translations in my models for an ArrayField. Something like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyModel(models.Model):
    choices = ArrayField(
        _('choices'),
        models.CharField(max_length=255),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('Comma-delimited list.')
    )
```

However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'set_attributes_from_name'
```

Should it be `verbose_name` instead, and if so, why? ArrayFields are not relations.

Comment: I think you swapped the order of the options, the first parameter should be the type over which you construct an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of an [**`ArrayField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) is:

> ```
> class ArrayField(base_field, size=None, **options)
> ```

So the type of the items that will be stored in the array.

So you can construct such field as:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyModel(models.Model):
    choices = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255),
        verbose_name=_('choices'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('Comma-delimited list.')
    )
```

Or you can name the `base_field` and `verbose_name` explicitly, then the order does not matter.